VS Code autocomplete doesnt work for certain python packages
Python Code in VS Code:
import discord
from seleniumbase import *
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://google.com")
time.sleep(6)

TOKEN = "token"

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.start(token=TOKEN)

The client.start() method autocompletes and shows all available methods for the client object while the driver.get() method couldnt be autocompleted and doesnt show any available methods. Its not highlighted and with hovering over it there is no comments about the function, instead it says "(function) get: Any". The code still executes and does what its supposed to do, however it would be much easier to code for me if i could get the autocomplete for the package to work. Is there any reason why it doesnt work ? Thanks in advance

This is a problem with the actual library itself not putting its required types within objects (probably). I don't think you can fix this with VScode

The SeleniumBase method summary: help_docs/method_summary.md. The available methods depend on the mode used. (They are generated at runtime.) For example, if uc=True, then the uc_click(selector) method exists to do a stealth click.

Micheal post it as an answer. This is the right explanation
